# Python Orbit Simulator using scipy.integrate.ode and dopri5 (Problems with getting solution)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, simulation

I'm currently creating an orbit simulator for uni, with specific instructions to use .ode instead of odeint and "dopri5".

I'm trying to find the x & y component of the Earth revolving around a stationary sun, as time increases. I'm having trouble extracting results.

Here is my code:

---

```
import math
import numpy as np
from Planet import Planet
from scipy.integrate import ode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Import file for data
infile = open("Earth.ini", "r")

#Read Earth data from file
P = Planet.from_file(infile)

def fun(t, z, c):
    r = np.linalg.norm(x)
    x = z[0]
    y = z[1]
    f = [-(c*x)/(r**3), y]
    return f

solver = ode(fun)
solver.set_integrator('dopri5')

G = 6.67408E-11
M = 1.9891E+30
c = G*M
solver.set_f_params(c)

t0 = 0.0
z0 = [P.position, P.velocity]
solver.set_initial_value(z0,t0)

t1 = 6.307E+7
N = 730
t = np.linspace(t0,t1,N)
z0 = np.asarray(z0)
z0 = np.concatenate(z0)
xlist = [z0[0]]
ylist = [z0[1]]

k = 1
while solver.successful() and solver.t<t1:
    solver.integrate(t[k])
    xlist.append(ode.z[0])
    ylist.append(ode.z[1])
    k +=1
```

---

I'm getting the error: AttributeError: type object 'ode' has no attribute 'z'
and another: C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate_ode.py:1035: UserWarning: dopri5: input is not consistent
self.messages.get(idid, 'Unexpected idid=%s' % idid))

I found an example code online, which I'm trying to adapt to mine, but instead I'm using vectors.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import ode


def fun(t, z, omega):
    """
    Right hand side of the differential equations
      dx/dt = -omega * y
      dy/dt = omega * x
    """
    x, y = z
    f = [-omega*y, omega*x]
    return f

# Create an `ode` instance to solve the system of differential
# equations defined by `fun`, and set the solver method to 'dop853'.
solver = ode(fun)
solver.set_integrator('dop853')

# Give the value of omega to the solver. This is passed to
# `fun` when the solver calls it.
omega = 2 * np.pi
solver.set_f_params(omega)

# Set the initial value z(0) = z0.
t0 = 0.0
z0 = [1, -0.25]
solver.set_initial_value(z0, t0)

# Create the array `t` of time values at which to compute
# the solution, and create an array to hold the solution.
# Put the initial value in the solution array.
t1 = 2.5
N = 75
t = np.linspace(t0, t1, N)
sol = np.empty((N, 2))
sol[0] = z0

# Repeatedly call the `integrate` method to advance the
# solution to time t[k], and save the solution in sol[k].
k = 1
while solver.successful() and solver.t < t1:
    solver.integrate(t[k])
    sol[k] = solver.y
    k += 1

# Plot the solution...
plt.plot(t, sol[:,0], label='x')
plt.plot(t, sol[:,1], label='y')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

---

If anyone can help, that would be great.